# Date passed from input type date seems to be empty and outputs ..1970-01-01

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms

I have a table .I want to update input  type date to the the table data.I want to pass this to a php form intermediate.php .But null value seems to be get passed and output seems to be `1970-01-01` which implies data is not getting passed.

```
 <form method="" action="intermediate.php">
   <table id="updatetable">
     
    </table>
  </form>
    //Jquery added here
    <script>
     var today = new Date();
     var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
     var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    
     today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
     var i;
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    updatetabledata += 
    '<td><input type="date"  id="vazhipadudate"'+i+'" 
    name="vazhipadudate' + i + ' " min="' + today + '"/>
     </td>';
   }
    $("#updatetable").empty().append(updatetabledata);
    </script>
```

Here is the php code snippet of intermediate.php

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
$date='vazhipadudate'.$i;
if(!empty( $_POST["$date"] ))
{/*echo "\n Date is  ..".$_POST["$date"];*/
$time = strtotime($_POST["$date"]);

//$storecart[$i]['date']=  $_POST["$date"];$storecart[$i]['date']
$time = strtotime($_POST["$date"]);
echo "The time now is.....".$time;
$storecart[$i]['date'] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
echo "Selected Date is..........".$storecart[$i]['date'] ;
}
}
```

Output is if I comment out   if(!empty( $_POST["$date"] ))

```
The time now is.....Selected Date is..........1970-01-01
The time now is.....Selected Date is..........1970-01-01
The time now is.....Selected Date is..........1970-01-01
The time now is.....Selected Date is..........1970-01-01
The time now is.....Selected Date is..........1970-01-01
```

Comment: I don't get it, you name your inputs `vazhipadudate` then you expect `$_POST["$date"]` (note the $ in the key name), plus it doesn't seem to be all you have there?

Comment: See @konrados $date='vazhipadudate'.$i

Comment: Your input name contains space at the end! Also why not `name="vazhipadudate[]"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made few changes in main file.
Add method:post, in js passing the today date in value attribute.
Now it works fine

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="intermediate.php">
       <table id="updatetable">
         
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="">
    </form>
    //JQuery Link here...
    <script>
     var today = new Date();
     var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
     var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    
     today = yyyy+ '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
     var i;
     var updatetabledata = "";
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        updatetabledata += '<td><input type="date" id="vazhipadudate' + i + '" name="vazhipadudate[]" min="' + today + '" value="' + today + '"></td>';
   }
    $("#updatetable").empty().append(updatetabledata);
    </script>
```

intermediate.php

```
<?php 
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['vazhipadudate']);$i++){
    echo "The time now is.....".date("Y-m-d").'&nbsp;';
    echo "Selected Date is..........".$_POST['vazhipadudate'][$i].'<br/>' ;
}
?>
```

Output

```
The time now is.....2020-07-10 Selected Date is..........2020-07-14
The time now is.....2020-07-10 Selected Date is..........2020-07-21
The time now is.....2020-07-10 Selected Date is..........2020-07-12
The time now is.....2020-07-10 Selected Date is..........2020-07-13
The time now is.....2020-07-10 Selected Date is..........2020-07-15
```

Comment: .I am still getting output as The time now is.....Selected Date is..........1970-01-01

Comment: .I want the selected date.Does this pass the selected date @Mohit Prajapati

Comment: @soman raj, Yes, check this now. Update few more thing.